# Ionic close IonicPopup when button makes an Ajax call

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Am new to both angular and ionic. I have a popup in my page where i show user a input field to enter the OTP and a submit button. When i click on the submit button, I make an Ajax call to check if the OTP is valid.

But am not able to close the popup with .close method. Please help

```
var OTPPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    title: 'OTP VERIFICATION',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login/otp.html',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons : [{
        text: 'Confirm OTP',
        type: 'button-assertive',
        onTap : function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var validateResponse = validateOTP();
            validateResponse.then(function(response){
                console.log('success', response);
                return response;
            });
        }
    }]
}).then(function(result){
    console.log('Tapped', result);
    OTPPopup.close();
});
```

And below is the function validateOTP

```
function validateOTP() {
    var requestObj = {
        authentication: {
            email_id: $scope.loginForm.email,
            security_code: $scope.OTP
        }
    };
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        activateUser(requestObj, function(response){
            if(response.error == null && response.data.isSuccess) {
                console.log('validate correct');
                resolve(response);
            } 
        }, function(response){
            return 'error';
        });
    });
}
```

`activateUser` is my service which makes the ajax call. Please let me know how can i acheive this.

`console.log('success', response)` is being printed inside the `.then` but after returning something from the `onTap` , the promise of the popup is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up solving it myself.

This solution would work only if you have exactly one ionicPopup on your page. I just wrote this line of code to do the trick

`$ionicPopup._popupStack[0].responseDeferred.resolve();`

This automatically closes the popup. The whole code is more simpler now with normal Ajax without any q promises.

```
var OTPPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    title: 'OTP VERIFICATION',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login/otp.html',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons : [{
        text: 'Confirm OTP',
        type: 'button-assertive',
        onTap : function(e) {
            // e.preventDefault() will stop the popup from closing when tapped.
            e.preventDefault();
            validateOTP();
        }
    }]
});
```

and in the next function

```
function validateOTP() {
    var requestObj = {
        authentication: {
            email_id: $scope.loginForm.email,
            security_code: $scope.loginForm.OTP
        }
    };
    activateUser(requestObj, function(response){
        if(response.error == null && response.data.isSuccess) {
            localStorage.setLocalstorage = response.data.user[0];
            $ionicPopup._popupStack[0].responseDeferred.resolve();
            $state.go('dashboard.classified');
        } 
    }, function(response){
    });
}
```

Comment: nice this really helped. I had an issue with my popup closing when a request goes through and transitions to a different state of my app. it would just be stuck. is this the best way to force close an ionic popup

Answer (score 0):

you don't need call e.preventDefault();

you just only return the validateOTP promise

ionicPopup will waiting the promise then close popup

```
var OTPPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    title: 'OTP VERIFICATION',
    template: 'templates/login/otp.html',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons : [{
        text: 'Confirm OTP',
        type: 'button-assertive',
        onTap : function() {
            return validateOTP();
        }
    }]
}).then(function(result){
    console.log('closed', result); // result is the activateUser resolve response
});
```

Comment: If i do not call preventDefault, it will close the popup even before the ajax starts. The issue here is that if the OTP entered is incorrect, the popup has to remain with an error message below the input. So preventDefault is needed here.